# Creating equation for position when the acceleration depends on the current position

Tags: kinematics, computational-physics, simulations, calculus

I am writing a simplified simulation of how a drone will move to a target destination.  The drone adjusts the acceleration based on the distance from the target location.

I want to use the equation for acceleration where c is the target location:
$$a(t) = c - x(t)$$
That makes the velocity (where v0 is the initial velocity):
$$v(t) = v0 + \int_0^tc-x(t')dt' $$
$$v(t) = v0 +ct - \int_0^tx(t')dt'$$

This is where it starts to get messy.  I then try to integrate again to get the position and end up with the function that is dependent upon itself:
$$x(t)=x0+\int_0^tv0+ct-\int_0^tx(t')dt'dt''$$
$$x(t)=x0+tv0+\frac{t^2c}2-\int_0^t\int_0^tx(t')dt'dt''$$

I'm not really sure how to work with this.  Is there an easier form I can put this in that will make it easier to program something to calculate the results?

Comment: @AaronStevens That sounds more like an answer rather than a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure! Instead of integrating, express your original equation in terms of $x(t)$, like so:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^2x(t)}{\mathrm{d}t^2} = c - x(t)$$

This is an [ordinary differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation) (ODE), which is a *very* well-studied type of equation. There are many computational (and mathematical) methods available to solve them.

If you want to do this computationally, I'd suggest you look around and find a library in your language of choice that includes an ODE solver, and just write some code to pass the appropriate parameters to it. Or, you may want to take the opportunity to write your own ODE solver to see how it works. The [Runge-Kutta algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods) (typically fourth order) is one well-known method that you might want to try, and that you can also find implemented in many software libraries. As you research more, you may find other methods that perform better for your case.

You can also solve the equation symbolically using standard techniques if you'd prefer to do so. It's a pretty easy one, as ODEs go; I'll leave the details for you to look up. The solution will, of course, have two arbitrary constants that you'll need to choose or calculate to match on the initial conditions of your situation.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I understand this was a basic problem, but I was stuck and I appreciate you taking the time to help

Comment: No problem. And just for future reference, upvoting an answer you like (and accepting it if you think it properly answers your question and is your favorite out of the answers you've received) is generally considered a good implicit way to say thanks around here. If you stick around, you'll notice that we're not too big on leaving comments to say thank you, although it is still appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Let me offer an analytical solution to a more general version of this equation.

$$ a = \frac{{\rm d}^2 x}{{\rm d}t^2} = c -\alpha^2 \, x \tag{1} $$

$$ \frac{{\rm d}v}{{\rm d}t}  = \frac{{\rm d}v}{{\rm d}x} \frac{{\rm d}x}{{\rm d}t} = v\,\frac{{\rm d}v}{{\rm d}x} \tag{2}$$

$$ \begin{aligned}
 v\,\frac{{\rm d}v}{{\rm d}x}  & = c - \alpha^2 x \\
\int v \,{\rm d}v & = \int (c- k x) {\rm d}x \\
 \tfrac{1}{2} v^2 - \tfrac{1}{2} v_0^2 & = c\, x - \tfrac{1}{2} \alpha^2 x^2
\end{aligned} \tag{3} $$

The above is a conservation of energy statement. Do you see it? Consider $v_0$ the velocity at time zero and the LHS the change in kinetic energy per unit mass. The RHS is the work done per unit mass.

The solution of the above is

$$ v(x) = \sqrt{ v_0^2 + 2 c x - \alpha^2 x^2} \tag{4}$$

Now time is introduced by ${\rm d}t = \frac{{\rm d}x}{{\rm d}t} {\rm d} t = \frac{1}{v} {\rm  d}x$

$$ t(x) = \int \frac{1}{v(x)}\,{\rm d}x = \frac{1}{\alpha} \sin^{-1} \left( \frac{ \alpha^2 x -c }{\sqrt{c^2+\alpha^2 v_0^2}} \right) \tag{5} $$

$$ \sin\left(\alpha t\right) = \frac{ \alpha^2 x -c }{\sqrt{c^2+\alpha^2 v_0^2}} \tag{6}$$

$$ \boxed{ x(t) =  \frac{ c + \left( \sqrt{c^2+\alpha^2 v_0^2} \right) \sin(\alpha t) }{\alpha^2}   } \tag{7} $$

This makes $\alpha$ the frequency of oscillation.

You can validate the result, by means of the constant $X = \sqrt{c^2+\alpha^2 v_0^2}$ and

$$ \begin{aligned}
   \frac{{\rm d}^2}{{\rm d}t^2} x & = c - \alpha^2 x \\
   \frac{{\rm d}^2}{{\rm d}t^2} \frac{c+X \sin(\alpha t)}{\alpha^2} & = c - \alpha^2 \frac{c+X \sin(\alpha t)}{\alpha^2} \\
  -X \sin(\alpha t) & = c - (X \sin(\alpha t)+c) \\
 -X \sin(\alpha t) & = -X \sin(\alpha t) \; \; \checkmark
\end{aligned} \tag{8}$$

Comment: _edit #1_ to fix an error in the solution (7).

Comment: For what it's worth, I deliberately avoided offering a solution to the equation. It's not what is being requested here (the question is asking _how_ to reach a solution, not _what_ the solution is), and more importantly, it veers too close to complete-answer-to-homework for my taste. Though because I posted an answer here, I'm saying this in my capacity as a regular user, not with my moderator "hat" on.

Comment: @DavidZ - I remember the first time I saw a direct integration solution for a spring like system as the one above and it was an aha! moment for me. I genuinely learned something that day. If there is _any_ chance that this answer can genuinely benefit the _op_  or future readers then there is merit here. I am offering a how that can be applied to other situations also.